# How can you force a wordbreak in HTML?

Tags: css, html

I have the following code.

```html
<tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-top: 10px;" bgcolor="#fffff">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="left" bgcolor="#c8f4ca" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
                                        Attraction Name:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="60%" align="right" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
                                        Arlington Hotel Celtic Night
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="25%" align="right" style="max-width: 25%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                       Email:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                        info@celticnights.com
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                       Website:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                        http://celticnights.com
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
                                       Reservation:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
                                        Required
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td align="left" style="padding-top: 10px;" bgcolor="#fffff">
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="left" bgcolor="#c8f4ca" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
                                        Attraction Name:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="60%" align="right" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
                                        Ashtown Castle
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="25%" align="right" style="max-width: 25%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                       Email:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                        phoenixparkvisitorcentre@opw.ie
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
                                       Website:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px; word-wrap: break-word;">
                                        http://www.heritageireland.ie/en/dublin/phoenixparkvisitorcentre-ashtowncastle/
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
                                       Reservation:
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
                                        Not Required
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

The problem is that the second attraction details does not seem to follow the maximum width. I know that this is occurring because of the long website url.

I have a couple of questions relating to this:

1. Why is the url not breaking onto multiple lines?
2. Is there a way I can force it into multiple lines without modifying the URL?

Comment: the links are already breaking into 2 lines.

Comment: @ShahilM yes but as you can see the width of the grey portion is greater than it is for the first attraction. Is there a way I can preserve the width?

Comment: table { table-layout: fixed; word-break:break-all }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use css rule `word-break: break-all;`

```css
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
   <td align="left" style="padding-top: 10px;" bgcolor="#fffff">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td width="40%" align="left" bgcolor="#c8f4ca" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
               Attraction Name:
            </td>
            <td width="60%" align="right" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
               Arlington Hotel Celtic Night
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="25%" align="right" style="max-width: 25%;">
         <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
               Email:
            </td>
            <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
               info@celticnights.com
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
               Website:
            </td>
            <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
               http://celticnights.com
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
               Reservation:
            </td>
            <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
               Required
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="left" style="padding-top: 10px;" bgcolor="#fffff">
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td width="40%" align="left" bgcolor="#c8f4ca" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
               Attraction Name:
            </td>
            <td width="60%" align="right" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px;">
               Ashtown Castle
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="25%" align="right" style="max-width: 25%;">
         <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
               Email:
            </td>
            <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
               phoenixparkvisitorcentre@opw.ie
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;">
               Website:
            </td>
            <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px; word-wrap: break-word;">
               http://www.heritageireland.ie/en/dublin/phoenixparkvisitorcentre-ashtowncastle/
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="25%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
               Reservation:
            </td>
            <td width="75%" align="left" bgcolor="#eeeeee" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 24px; padding: 15px 10px 20px 10px;">
               Not Required
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Your answer worked, but I would like to know why you recommend to use a separate css code. Like can I not just replace where I have `word-wrap: break-word;` with `word-break: break-all;`?

Comment: In contrast to word-wrap, word-break will create a break at the exact place where text would otherwise overflow its container (even if putting an entire word on its own line would negate the need for a break)

Comment: Yea that makes sense. But I was wondering why you included is a separate css section? if it has any value or is just purely preference?

Comment: table { table-layout: fixed; word-break:break-all }

Comment: Hmm, it is not a preference. But you should write your css separately from HTML code, it is less messy and more maintainable. In the HTML code you posted you are repeating your self very much with all the styles. Also do not use HTML formatting like `bgcolor`, rather use css.